# SQLite, Update Statement using DateTime

Tags: sqlite

I have been trying to update a datetime column using the following SQL Statement:

```
UPDATE HistoricData SET RecordDate=DATETIME(RecordDate,'60 minutes') WHERE DataStreamID=1 AND TimeFrameID=5
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
NOT NULL Constraint Failed: HistoricData.RecordDate
```

If you could recommend the appropriate change to get this working, I would very much appreciate it.

I will attempt to attach a sample schema and data:

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqSBQ.png)

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bvVB.png)

Comment: And what do you get with this one: `SELECT DATETIME(RecordDate,'60 minutes') FROM HistoricData WHERE DataStreamID=1 AND TimeFrameID=5`? As far I can tell, there is nothing wrong with your DML statement. With simplified schema works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f4651/7.

Comment: `DATETIME` works with format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` by default, but you are using `YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS` in your `RecordDate` column.

Comment: Hi Bedla,Thank you for your help, I changed the import procedure so that it uses '-' and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting your DML, my only remaining concern was the datetime format you have in your table. I tried updating such a value as you did, and guess what, it returns NULL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f4651/10 Why? Because your strings (do notation) are not valid [ISO-8601](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) strings. You probably need to simply replace the dots with dashes before updating (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f4651/11).

Comment: Hi ZorgoZ, thank you for your help, changing the import so that it uses '-' instead of '.' fixes the problem.